# Multiple Integral using Integration by Parts?

Tags: integration

So basically I need to prove the following integral over the sphere: $x_1^2+...+x_{3N}^2\leq R^2$
$$\int...\int 4\pi r_1^2...4\pi r_N^2dr_1...dr_N=\frac{(8\pi R^3)^N}{(3N)!}$$
Using the result of the volume of a 3N Sphere, which I already showed was equal to $$V_{3N}=\frac{\pi^{3N/2}}{\Gamma(3N/2+1)}R^{3N}$$

I was thinking of using Integration by parts, such that the integral reduces to one where I can use the Volume of the 3N-Sphere, but I am not sure if that'll work.
I really need a hint on this one.

Thanks

Comment: The integration region is missing.

Comment: Presumably $n$ and $N$ are meant to be the same variable?

Answer (score 0):

The formula is wrong. Already for $n=1$ the result is $\frac{8\pi R^3}3\ne\frac{8\pi R^3}{3!}$. For $n=2$ it's

$$
(8\pi R^3)^2\int_0^1\mathrm dx_1x_1^2\int_0^\sqrt{1-x_1^2}\mathrm dx_2x_2^2=(8\pi R^3)^2\int_0^1\mathrm dx_1x_1^2\left(1-x^2\right)^\frac32=(8\pi R^3)^2\frac\pi{32}\ne\frac{(8\pi R^3)^2}{6!}\;.
$$

Comment: I am sorry there was a mistake in the question: The integral goes over the 3N Sphere and, but the integrands are in the individual radii.